# applet NullPointerException

Tags: java, applet, nullpointerexception

I've been working on a game in an applet. In Eclipse it has been working completely fine, but when I sign it and load it in my browser, it throws a NullPointerException, without any further information. What can I do?

Comment: Could you provide the full stack trace and code that the stack trace is referencing?

Comment: Are you sure about "without any further information"? Can't get a stack-trace?

Comment: I dont know how to recieve stack trace...

Comment: Ensure that every catch has `e.printStackTrace();` & open the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml)..

Comment: this is what it gave me: http://pastebin.com/vrjJe2AL

Comment: That's a thread stack listing, not an exception stack trace.

Comment: sys.out(e.getMessage) would be more useful also with no code, are to just guess what you are doing wrong? Even with a trace, no matter where it points, all I can tell you is that you failed to intialize something you are calling - as long as i can't see your code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give very much information here, but I can make a guess that you are calling `getAppletContext` and it is returning null, because the browser's java implementation is broken. Try the applet viewer, and try a different browser, and see if it works there.

Answer (score 0):

That happen to me once. You'll need to go to:

- Configure Java.

  - Security.
  - Exception List
  - Edit the list adding the directory of your applet.

This, I think, should fix the problem!